# If there's no pokemon to begin with, will incense help?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in the middle of nowhere with an M-cell. There is no pokemon near me 99% of the time. When i pop an incense, will it attract pokemon even though theres none to begin with?

Comment: Despite the description of incense and lure modules, Pokemon ***spawn*** around lures and incense at regular intervals, they aren't actually existing spawns drawn towards the area..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pokemon tend to spawn in more populated areas such as malls and town centres, due to where you live "in the middle of nowhere" you've likely been handicapped in the Pokemon catching sense, however, incense and lures will not attract Pokemon but make them spawn near you more oftenly and increasing rarity of Pokemon. If possible, try to go near places where it's oftenly densely populated and places that harbour many Pokestops to increase the chances of finding a Pokemon. Good luck on finding your first Pidgey!

Comment: So essentially, an incense isn't effected by the populace of the general area?

Comment: It likely isn't, however moving greatly increases the chances you'll find a pokemon, up to 5x actually, as with incense on you'll get atleast 1 pokemon every 5 minutes, however you can get up to 1 pokemon per minute per 200m you travel :https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4t5vu0/psa_incense_spawns_1_pok%C3%A9mon_every_5_min_while/

Comment: So optimally, I would pop an incense, and walk around the outside of my house until it runs out?

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeees